# httpsProxyAgent is not defined

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am integrating linkedin authentication with my node.js by passport-linkedin.
It works fine initially. I am redirected to login/signup page. User is entering their details but then when it is coming to authentication I get the error

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:379:17)
    at C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:166:45
    at C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:199:18
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:170:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I checked on stack overflow and got to know that it is because of corporate proxy. I added

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

if (process.env['https_proxy']) {
        httpsProxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env['https_proxy']);
}
```

and

```
options.agent = httpsProxyAgent;
```

in oauth2.js. But now I am getting this error

```
ReferenceError: httpsProxyAgent is not defined
    at exports.OAuth2._request (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:126:19)
    at exports.OAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:197:8)
    at loaded (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:164:20)
    at NullStore.verify (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\state\null.js:9:3)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:210:26)
    at attempt (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:361:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\SU40006113\Desktop\second\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

I have installed ***https-proxy-agent***.

What's causing the error?

Comment: may seem too simple, but do you have your env variable set for `https_proxy`

Comment: How do I do that?  @LostJon

Comment: It worked fine. :)